# Problem with Search: I can do everything locally and I can't do anything on the server

Tags: search, cron

Production site

- FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p9
- mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for portbld-freebsd8.2 (amd64) using
  5.2
- nginx version: nginx/1.0.14

Local copy of the site

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Drupal version 6.19

When I use search locally, it functions properly. When I use search on the production server it fails with the response: *Your search yielded no results.*

I truncated and imported all of the search tables from the working copy to the non-working copy.

I tried to run a re-index on the production site and it errors out with this message: *An HTTP error 500 occurred. /vacation/batch/?id=2&op=do*

Is the MySQL database the issue here? What other troubleshooting techniques can help me nail this down?

Comment: so far I am also checking for time outs either with PHP or sockets.

Comment: In running drush search-index, I keep getting this error:

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                       [error]
Error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /includes/common.inc(1695) : eval()'d code:13

Comment: So, I have an rss feed that is using file_get_content() but not parsing properly causing a fault while running search-index or search-reindex. Does anyone have any suggestions about where to go form here?

Comment: PHP 5.4.3 (cli) (built: Jun  2 2012 06:28:51) on the server
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 17:19:58)

Comment: I found this bit of information:"PHP 5.4.0 breaks a few modules in D6, haven't done a lot of testing in D7 yet, I would assume we will find the same problems there. The major issue we have found, is that PHP 5.4.0 has finally removed "call time pass by reference" it has been deprecated for a while, and we have been warned since PHP 5.2(??) that it was going away. It's gone, and thus any code using it will simply fail, it's no longer an option to just turn off the warning."